# Forward declaration of function messes up, saying args are undeclared identifiers

Tags: c++, function, forward-declaration, function-calls

This is my code:

- mainheader.h

  ```
  void displaygrid(int (* _grid)[10][10] , string msg );
  ```
- something.cpp

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include "mainheader.h"

  void displaygrid(int (* _grid)[10][10], string msg = "" )
  {
     //body goes here
  }
  ```

Compiler says at line of forward declaration in header:

> _grid and string are undeclared identifiers

however since its just prototype, it shouldnt be worried about existence of `_grid`, right ?

Also, header is included after the string , but it doesnt know about string as well. It looks like its trying to call function instead of forward declaring. What's wrong?

Comment: When posting a question about compiler or linker errors, it is always helpful to include the actual errors. Not edited or shorted down but complete and unedited.

Comment: Also, ALWAYS have your default values in the header file (and _NOT_ in the implementation - otherwise, some smart guy will change one, and not the other, and either it won't work as expected, or someone else will think "What the **** does this value come from". Default arguments are added by the compiler when it compiles the function - which typically happens from the header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `string` you have to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to know about __grid in the header as well as string - forward declare or not.  You need to at least place a `struct __grid;` somewhere above it or the likes so it has some sort of clue of what it is.  Same for string...

Comment: `_grid` is a name of a variable, not a struct

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <string>` in your `mainheader.h` and refer to `string` as `std::string`. You also need to include whatever is necessary to get `_grid`:

```
//mainheader.h
#include <string>
void displaygrid(int (* _grid)[10][10] , std::string msg );
```

Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698205/c-headers-redefining-declaring-mixup/14698224#14698224).

Answer (score 0):

You also want the default argument in the header file, not in the implementation, because you want code that calls it to *know* that `msg` can be defaulted.