# Compiling Helper file with functions

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm at a loss - i'm just getting into C++ and for some reason this is not working out for me. So i'm using Netbeans, and i've got the following main file:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    f("help");

    return 0;
}
```

Functions.h file:

```
#include <string>

#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

void f( string a );

#endif
```

and Functions.cpp file:

```
#include "functions.h"

void f( string a ) {
    return;
}
```

So, long story short, it doesn't compile. It says it can't understand the string variable? I don't get it, i tried moving the include for string all over the place but nowhere seems to help.  What do i do?

Comment: learn to  not use "using namespace std;"

Comment: You can think of the problem this way:  it's real name isn't `string` -- it's `std::string`.  Don't cheat by using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Why? Is it considered bad practice?

Comment: @user1288167:  Yes, it's a bad practice.  In short, it undos all the benefits of using namespaces in the first place.  Learn to use namespaces, not work around them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to use `std::string`, you have to `#include <string>` in your functions header, and call it `std::string`,since it is in the `std` namespace.

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <string>

void f( std::string a );

#endif
```

See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698205/c-headers-redefining-declaring-mixup/14698224#14698224) and also [why is 'using namespace std' considered bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include string header file in `Functions.h`, also tell compiler that `string` is from `std` namespace.

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <string>
void f( std::string a );

#endif
```

Functions.cpp file:

```
#include "functions.h"

void f( std::string a ) {
    return;
}
```

Better practice is to pass string by const reference

```
void f(const std::string& a ) {
    return;
}
```

See [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: Can I get around this by writing that "using namespace std;" line in my other files? Or is it good practice to write it in?

Comment: Yes you can but that's not good program practice. See my updated answer regarding `using namespace std;`

Comment: @user1288167:  Please don't get in to the bad habit of `using namespace std`.  It will only cause you and your colleagues grief.

Comment: Ok, i'm not opposed to learning to not use it, but why does it cause grief?

Comment: @user1288167: Because of name ambiguity.  See the link provided in bilz's answer for a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Include the standard header: `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```